# Stop arbitrary fill color change in Excel or apply conditional formatting with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet that I applied the following conditional formatting to, to improve readability

[image: Conditional formating]

I found out however that I lose the colours every now and then - Excel changes RGB values of the fill colours to something completely different from what I originally used

To fix this (before I distribute the excel file) I am hoping to recreate the conditional formating above in VBA and attach it to many of the combo-boxes on the spreadsheet

The idea is as follows:

- Check column C2:c100 , when the value
- if cellvalue is 1,

  - set rows in range I8:K800, M8:M800 to colour 2
  - apply outline + outline colour to rows in range I8:K800, M8:M800
- if cellvalue is 2

  - set rows in range I8:K800, M8:M800 to colour 2
  - apply outline + outline colour to rows in range I8:K800, M8:M800

etc

I have this code

```
Sub ColorCells()
Dim Data As Range
Dim cell As Range
Set currentsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set Data = currentsheet.Range("C2:C200")

For Each cell In Data

If cell.Value = "1" Then
Range("A" & Data.Row, "H" & Data.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 10

End If
Next

End Sub
```

I'm struggling with line 8; to apply the color/formatting to my desired range and will be happy for any help / someone can point out what I'm doing wrong

I prefer to use conditional formating here so will be happier if anyone can reveal the reason for the colour-shifting.

Comment: This is just a shot in the dark, but if you're using "ObjectThemeColor", and then changing the template theme/palette, that might explain the change in colors. It is possible to do VBA to create the format conditions, specifying the literal RGB values, which is probably preferably to your current approach, since it will still *function* as "conditional formatting".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the vba here `Range("A" & Data.Row, "H" & Data.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 10` you use `Data.Row`, but you should reference to `cell.Row`

[Range.Row](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196952.aspx) returns the number of the first row. So in your code you only change the first row every time.

Hope this helps.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

One possible cause of your colors changing, is that the user(s) might be changing the Theme colors. Any colors assigned an `ThemeColor` are dynamic and responsive to changing Theme colors, for instance:

[image]

[image]

It is possible to do VBA to create the format conditions, specifying the literal RGB values, which is probably preferably to your current approach, since it will still function as "conditional formatting".

My approach would be to use the Macro Recorder, and record the actions of creating all of your formatting conditions. Then you can modify it in such a way to "hard-code" the color values.

Here is a brief example; I recorded a macro and then modified the output code a bit to replicate your first format condition (I'm not 100% sure I have the same color, but this should give you the structure):

```
Sub ConditionalFormats()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cFormat As FormatCondition
    Set rng = Range("E8:G802")

    Set cFormat = rng.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$C$8=4")
    cFormat.SetFirstPriority
    cFormat.StopIfTrue = False
    With cFormat.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        ' ### This was the original output using ThemeColor property
        ' .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight2
        ' ### Modify using Color property instead:
        .Color = 15849925
        ' ### TintAndShade is not needed if we're using the literal color value
        '.TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
    End With

    '## To add another condition, redefine the rng and add a new condition as needed:
    Set rng = Range("I8:O802")
    Set cFormat = rng.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$C$8=4")
    With cFormat.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 15849925
    End With
    '## Add code for borders, etc.
    With cFormat.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = vbBlack
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With cFormat.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = vbBlack
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
End Sub
```

Now, the formatting rules aren't dependent on the Theme colors, so even if user changes the Theme, the colors remain. (The pink cell above is **not** conditionally formatted, so it does change with the Theme, but the blue cells do not):

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation, I'm adapting it now for my use